# Convergence of heavy-ball method for non-convex optimization

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

The heavy-ball method (also called gradient descent with momentum) is commonly used in optimization. The update rule can be written as:
$$x_{t+1}=x_t-\eta\nabla f(x_t)-\beta (x_t-x_{t-1})$$
Suppose $\eta$ and $\beta$ are constants. It has been proven that for convex function $f$, the Heavy-ball method converges globally. However, for non-convex setting, I can not find any literature which proved the convergence of the algorithm. Here convergence for a non-convex function means that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find a point $x$ such that $\|\nabla f(x)\|_2\le \epsilon$. Does the algorithm really have convergence guarantee in non-convex settings? If it does, what is the convergence rate of the algorithm? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at this paper "Heavy-ball method in nonconvex optimization problems"?

Comment: It seems that the I must spend a lot of money buying the pdf. Does this paper prove the convergence of heavy-ball method?

Comment: https://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01128757

Comment: Thank you very much. I have browsed the paper successfully. This paper proved the convergence of heavy-ball method, but it did not show a convergence rate. Can we show that under $L$ smooth property, after $T$ steps, we can find a point $x$ such that $\|\nabla f(x)\|^2\le O(L/T)$, for example? (This bound applies for traditional gradient descent.)

Comment: Please read this paper "iPiano: Inertial Proximal Algorithm for Nonconvex Optimization". In Section 4, heavy ball method reduces the to case where $g=0$. Moreover, in this paper, the asymptotic convergence rate that $\min\limits_{0\leq i\leq N}\|x_{i+1}-x_i\|^2=O(1/N)$ was given. And if $\alpha_n$ is constant, you can prove that $\|\nabla f(x_n)\|^2$ has the same asymptoticc convergence rate. For non asympototic convergence rate, I think you need the KL inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: May I consult you further about the stochastic case of heavy ball method? For SGD algorithm, we can prove convergence if one decays the step size gradually. However, I can not prove convergence of heavy ball method using the same technique as in the deterministic case.